# Need help with the graph of a function

Tags: optimization

In the optimization problem max: $$6x+2xy-2x^2-2y^2$$ subject to $x+2y\le2$ and $-x+y^2\le1$ I need to draw the graph of the feasible region in order to determine if the problem has global solutions, but I don't know what the graph of $-x+y^2=1$ looks like.

Comment: I have added LaTeX to your post, please make sure the edits are correct.

Comment: The function $-x+y^2=1$ is a parabola.

Comment: @Rana I think y^2=ax is a parabola; does that mean that a=(x+1)/x ? Isn't it wrong for a to be expressed in terms of x? How do I recognize a parabola? I know it may sound incredible, but yes, I already know the Kuhn-Tucker method for optimizing and yet I haven't been taught about parabolas.

Answer (score 0):

The region is the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $y^2-1 < x < 2-2y$.  It's fairly easy to visualize if you plot $x=y^2-1$ and $x=2-2y$.  It looks like so:

[image]

If you plot the function $f(x,y) = 6 x + 2 xy - 2 x^2 - 2 y^2$ over this region, you get something like so:

[image]

Now, if the critical point happens to be a saddle point, then the extreme must lie on the boundary.

[image]

Comment: I've been researching, and it seems that a function whose graph is a parabola is like this: (y-k)^2=4p(x-h) , not like y^2=x+1. How do I recognize a parabola?

Comment: I should have been more specific, my question is not how to solve the optimization problem, my question is how to recognize a parabola; I didn´t tag my question as optimization, someone edited the label

Comment: @Werther, if you substitute $k=0,p=\frac{1}{4},h=-1$ in the equation of the parabola $(y-k)^2=4p(x-h)$, then it becomes $y^2=x+1$. The easisest way to recognize parabola is to have aa equation involving quadratic equation of one variable among x,y and linear function of the other. Hope it helps.